# Retrieving data from XML file into variables

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that has got the following structure:

```
<root>
    <body>
        <e1>
            <en>
                <tag1>testt1</tag1>
                <tag2 user="anonym">testt2</tag2>
                <tag3>testt3</tag3>
                <tag4>testt4</tag4>
                <tag5>
                    <t51>tttt</t51>
                    <t52>ttt</t52>
                    <t53>ttt</t53>
                </tag5>
            </en>
            <r1>1</r1>
            <r2>
                <tr1>0</tr1>
            </r2>
        </e1>
        <r1>
        </r1>
        <r2>
        </r2>
    </body>
    <info>
    </info>
</root>
```

I need to get the data from `<e1>` element into certain variables for further usage. For this purpose, I am doing the following:

```
foreach (XElement elem in xmlDoc.Descendants("body").Descendants("e1"))
{
    tag1 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag1").Value;
    tag2 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag2").Value;
    tag2a = elem.Element("en").Element("tag2").Attribute("user").Value;
    tag3 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag3").Value;
    tag4 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag4").Value;
    t51 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag5").Element("t51").Value;
    t52 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag5").Element("t52").Value;
    t53 = elem.Element("en").Element("tag5").Element("t53").Value;
    r1 = elem.Element("r1").Value;
    tr1 = elem.Element("r2").Element("tr1").Value;
}
```

It is working properly, but I think, it's kinda looks not the best way. I am new to `XDocuments` and working with `XML` in `C#`. Was curious, if there is any more optimal way to do this?

Comment: Hi, updated my answer given you code ,can you please have a look , that is efficient way of doing thing

Answer (score 0):

I found way to do it very easily ,below is my code ,

In my code I am reading value of you xml string which is given by you in question, and after reading storing it into dictionary object.

```
   static Dictionary<string, string> ele = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private static void ReadAllElements(XElement node)
    {
        if (node.HasElements)
        {
            foreach (var element in node.Elements())
                ReadAllElements(element);
        }
        else
        {
            ele[node.Name.ToString()] = node.Value;
            if (node.HasAttributes)
            {
                foreach (var att in node.Attributes())
                    ele[node.Name.ToString() + att.Name.ToString()] = att.Value;
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("XMLFile1.xml", FileMode.Open);
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fs);
        var rows=(from row in xDoc.Descendants("e1").Elements()
                     select row).ToList();
        foreach (XElement node in rows)
            ReadAllElements(node);
        foreach (var keypair in ele)
            Console.WriteLine($"{keypair.Key} : {keypair.Value}");
        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Output will be

```
tag1 : testt1
tag2 : testt2
tag2user : anonym
tag3 : testt3
tag4 : testt4
t51 : tttt
t52 : ttt
t53 : ttt
r1 : 1
tr1 : 0
```

---

I suggest you make use of XML(de)Serialization instead of doing this, that is much clearner way to do it and you dont have to do this much long code and remember things.

For doing XML(de)Serialization you need as class simimlar to your structure of xml. So to get similar structure you make use of visual studio : [Visual Studio Generate Class From JSON or XML](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2015/07/introduction-below-article-is-on-one-of.html)

```
  XmlSerializer serializer = new
    XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassName you create));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
    ClassName i;
    i = (ClassName)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But, don’t you think that at the end I will do almost the same, just by assigning class elements values to the variables. FYI, I must assign values to these defined variables. So there will not be any advantage of using a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative, quick and precise way to pull the data from xml. Using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/) - an open source library to extract data from CSV/XML/Json files.

```
using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample10.xml").WithXPath("/root/body/e1")
    .WithField("tag1", xPath: "en/tag1")
    .WithField("tag2", xPath: "en/tag2")
    .WithField("tag2a", xPath: "en/tag2/@user")
    .WithField("tag3", xPath: "en/tag3")
    .WithField("tag4", xPath: "en/tag4")
    .WithField("t51", xPath: "en/tag5/t51")
    .WithField("t52", xPath: "en/tag5/t52")
    .WithField("t53", xPath: "en/tag5/t53")
    .WithField("r1", xPath: "r1")
    .WithField("r2", xPath: "r2/tr1")
)
{
    foreach (dynamic rec in parser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rec.DumpAsJson());

        //To access individual memnbers as below
        //Console.WriteLine(rec.tag1);
        //Console.WriteLine(rec.tag2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tag1": "testt1",
  "tag2": "testt2",
  "tag2a": "anonym",
  "tag3": "testt3",
  "tag4": "testt4",
  "t51": "tttt",
  "t52": "ttt",
  "t53": "ttt",
  "r1": 1,
  "r2": 0
}
```

Hope this helps.